# How can I disable Collection View but Header left enbled?

Tags: ios, swift, selection, collectionview, disable

I need to disallow Collection View selection, but left CV's header enabled?

Both methods block header. How to enable it?

```
CollectionView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

or

```
CollectionView.allowsSelection = false
```

Here is UICollectionReusableView:

```
final class HeaderCollectionReusableView: UICollectionReusableView {
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        
        addSubView()
        setupLayout()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    static let headerIdentifier = "HeaderCollectionReusableView"
    
    private func addSubView() {
        
        addSubview(collectionView)
    }
    
    public lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        
        var flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        flowLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        flowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width:  UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width / 3.5, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width / 3)
        flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 12
        flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 20, bottom: 0, right: 20)
        var view = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)
        view.register(cell: CollectionViewCell.self)
        view.backgroundColor = .clear
        view.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        view.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        view.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .automatic
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()
    
    private func setupLayout() {
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
            collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width / 3),
        ])
    }
}
```

This is horizontal CV embedded in other vertical CV's header.
I need to disable vertical CV but left enabled horizontal CV in vertical CV' header )

Comment: Please share your code for the header view.

Comment: @Asteroid code shared)

Comment: Can't you disable user interaction on the collection view and enable it just for the header view, which you have access to? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614965-headerview

Comment: @cora I cant ) I disable CV user interaction and its header disables too.

Comment: Did you try to disable for each cell (in cell For Row) ?

Comment: @claude31 Nope. But I solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To block I used `CollectionView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false` and it blocks everything even header.

I tried `CollectionView.allowsSelection = false` and it blocks CV and doesn't block header!

It works.

Before I just didn't pay attention that `.allowSelection` doesn't block header .